# Is there an equivalent to Python's defaultdict in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

I'd like to have an Elixir map where any key has a default value of a certain type. What is the best way to use or implement something like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest one is to use `Map.get/3` like this:

```
iex(1)> map = %{foo: "bar"}
%{foo: "bar"}
iex(2)> Map.get map, :foo, "baz"
"bar"
iex(3)> Map.get map, :fiz, "baz"
"baz"
```

If you don't like to specify the default value every time, you can create function, that "hides" the default:

```
iex(4)> my_get = &(Map.get &1, &2, "baz")
#Function<12.90072148/2 in :erl_eval.expr/5>
iex(5)> my_get.(map, :foo)
"bar"
iex(6)> my_get.(map, :fiz)
"baz"
```

If your map does not change, you can create a function, that takes only the key as an argument:

```
iex(7)> my_get2 = &(Map.get map, &1, "baz")
#Function<6.90072148/1 in :erl_eval.expr/5>
iex(8)> my_get2.(:fiz)
"baz"
iex(9)> my_get2.(:foo)
"bar"
```

EDIT after @whatyouhide comment:
If you need more versatile solution, like different defaults for different keys, you can first define the factory:

```
factory = fn (key) -> key end
map_ret_val = fn (nil, key) -> factory.(key)
                 (other, _key) -> other end
my_get3 = fn (map, key) -> map_ret_val.(map[key], key) end
```

Comment: I agree on creating a map which has *the same* default value for all missing keys by wrapping `Map.get/3`; it's a very clean solution provided only one default value is needed. Nice answer!

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, that Python `defaultdict` can have different default values for different keys. I updated my answer to address that.